# Hive/Impala UDF with String input/output

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala, udf

I am looking into Impala/Hive UDF examples, e.g.:

```
public class FuzzyEqualsUdf extends UDF {
    public FuzzyEqualsUdf() {
    }

    public BooleanWritable evaluate(DoubleWritable x, DoubleWritable y) {
        double EPSILON = 0.000001f;
        if (x == null || y == null)
            return null;
        return new BooleanWritable(Math.abs(x.get() - y.get()) < EPSILON);
    }
}
```

Then I tried to create my own UDF, which has String as input and String as output. Ideally, it should look like:

```
public class MyUdf extends UDF {
    public MyUdf() {
    }

    public StringWritable evaluate(StringWritable x) {
        String[] y = x.split(",");
        String z = y[0] + "|" + y[1] 
        return new StringWritable(z);
    }
}
```

However, my problem is there is no `StringWritable` class! I only see:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.ByteWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.ShortWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.TimestampWritable;
```

How do I make a udf with String type input/output without StringWritable class? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edamame. Probably , you can use org.apache.hadoop.io.Text class.

you can refer one of Hive's Built-in function . I referred to Trim which takes string and outputs string

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFBaseTrim.java

Answer (score 0):

It turns out just using Java String type for the input/output would work fine.

```
public String evaluate(String x) {
    String[] y = x.split(",");
    String z = y[0] + "|" + y[1] 
    return new StringWritable(z);
}
```

Additional Impala doc: http://impala.io/doc/html/TestUdf_8java_source.html